# iTunesConnect submission "app loads no content" with Black Screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect

I'm doing an pre-release submission to iTunesConnect.  My app is getting rejected and the response I'm getting from apple is very strange.  The app runs fine for me on iPhone 4s/5/5s/6/6+ if I build+deploy it from Xamarin with the App Store build provisioning profile.  But when I submit to iTunesConnect it's getting rejected and they're claiming:

> We still discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on
>   iPhone running iOS 8.3 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> Specifically we still found your app loads no content.

They also supply a black screenshot which leads me to believe that the app won't even run for them and launches and freezes on a black screen.  We asked them for more details and they gave us a very vague response that didn't help.  I did notice that the screen shot appears to come from an iPhone 4s.  I have confirmed that this app store provisioned build runs on my iPhone 4s with iOS 8.3.

Any suggestions?  How is apple running this IPA I submit different than how Xamarin is deploying it to my device?  Could this a Xamarin issue?

[image]

----------- EDIT -----------

Here is the NSDictionary launchOptions code I referred to in comments

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // Call base
        base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);

        // Handle launch options
        if (launchOptions != null)
        { 
            this.PerformLaunchOptions(launchOptions);
        }    
        else
        {
#if USE_HIDESTATUSBAR               
            // Hide status bar
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarHidden(true, false);
#endif

            // Init stuff
            // Call root view controller
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What do you do at app launch that might result in no VC being presented? Anything dynamic? Anything that might be timing out in a production build that running under Xcode might be masking? Have you tried the steps listed here about "How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions"? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/_index.html

Comment: Try creating ad-hoc ipa and test it yourself. It might be a problem with initial viewcontroller or something like that. Try clean, remove app, reinstall

Comment: In AppDelegate we are checking for the NSDictionary launchOptions in the FinishedLaunching method to handle app wake-ups from background.  I wonder if they are booting it up with some launch options and causing it to black screen...  I put that code above.  Yes we have been looking through that reference and trying things.

Comment: @SilviuSt We did.  We have been successfully running Ad-Hoc builds for months now, and we can even successfully run the App store build on devices.

Comment: It might be a localisation problem? Check if you're having a localized storyboard or stuff like that. It at you works and at them not, it must be a something-like-that problem.

Comment: Have you tested on other devices too? I got the same response from apple, and the screenshot given by them didn't helped. After a couple of replies, they explained that the the problem was that on iPad the app didn't show the content (a bug of my app).

Comment: @DiegoSuárez Interesting.  Our app is built universal but we haven't tested on iPad real device at all aside from the simulator.  I'll try that; however the screenshot they sent us was the resolution of an iPhone 4s.  So we're thinking it could be an issue with the NSDictionary launchOptions in FinishedLaunching.  Our app never starts with launch options, but we thinking that apple might test by sending it launch options and that's where our app is dying out (